# How to show codes without exiting presentation mode in PowerPoint

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, projector

Actually tomorrow I have to give a presentation in a workshop for my juniors.

And I want to show presentation(ppt) which will contain points and along-with it I will want to show them by writing the codes. But the problem is that whenever I have to switch to code editor from the PowerPoint, presentation mode exits and I have to restart it, breaking the rhythm.
So can someone suggest me about how I can show code editor on  projector without exiting the presentation mode.

I am using windows OS.

Comment: What code editor are you using? And what is the screen mode: **Duplicate** or **Extend**? I just tested a presentation on my desktop with two monitors and there was no need to close the presentation to show the other window and then switch back to the presentation.

Comment: Do you need to actually RUN the code you've entered? If not, perhaps add an action button and have it launch an instance of NOTEPAD.EXE or some other editor. That'll leave the slide show running.  Or possibly better: Open the presentation containing your code or that you want to add code to.  Press ALT+F11 to open the IDE. Open the presentation that you want to show the students and press F5 to start the screenshow. From there on, you can use ALT+TAB to switch between the two presentations, the IDE and anything else you want to have open.

Comment: Actually I will use VS code editor to show practical use of common html elements, and will also view the page in browser

Comment: @RishabhRyber In that case, the method I suggested should work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the problem, I just changed Projection settings from the PowerPoint Presentation mode and then every-time I switched to another workspace to show codes and output, while I did presentation in one workspace.